# How can i solve " Predis\ClientException : Command 'EXiSTS' is not a registered Redis command. " error?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, command, predis

I use redis class in the my custom provider but doesn't work on the server .

There aren't any problems on the local but i didn't understand why it doesn't work on the server.

When i use artisan commands i get this error.

" Predis\ClientException  : Command 'EXiSTS' is not a registered Redis command.

at /var/www/vhosts/website.com/laravel_folder/website/vendor/predis/predis/src/Profile/RedisProfile.php:88
    84|     {
    85|         $commandID = strtoupper($commandID);
    86|
    87|         if (!isset($this->commands[$commandID])) {

> 88|             throw new ClientException("Command '$commandID' is not a registered Redis command.");
>       89|         }
>       90|
>       91|         $commandClass = $this->commands[$commandID];
>       92|         $command = new $commandClass();

Exception trace:

1   Predis\Profile\RedisProfile::createCommand("EXiSTS")
      /var/www/vhosts/website.com/laravel_folder/website/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:323

2   Predis\Client::createCommand("exists")
      /var/www/vhosts/website.com/laravel_folder/website/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:314

Please use the argument -v to see more details. 
"

My code :

```
public function boot()
    {
        $redis = new Redis();

        if ( !$redis->exists('activity_of_week') ) {
            $redis->set('activity_of_week',serialize( Activity::ofWeek(10) ));
        }

        if ( !$redis->exists('popular_companies') ) {
            $redis->set('popular_companies',serialize( TopRateCompanies::sortBy()->take(10) ));
        }

        $activityOfWeeks = $redis->get('activity_of_week');
        $popularCompanies = $redis->get('popular_companies');

        $popular = new PopularCategory();
        $popularCategories = $popular->take(10);

        View::composer('frontend.layout.footer', function ($view) use ($activityOfWeeks, $popularCompanies, $popularCategories) {
            /**
             * @var ViewAlias $view
             */

             $keys = [  'email'         => 'contact-email',
                        'facebook'      => 'facebook',
                        'instagram'     => 'instagram',
                        'twitter'       => 'twitter',
                        'youtube'       => 'youtube',
                        'phone'         => 'contact-phone',
                    ];

            $info = array_map( [$this,'contactInfo'],$keys );

            $view->with('contact', $info)
                    ->with('activityOfWeeks', $activityOfWeeks)
                    ->with('popularCompanies', $popularCompanies)
                    ->with('popularCategories', $popularCategories);
        });
    }

    public function contactInfo($key)
    {
        return Settings::where('key',$key)->firstOrFail()->value;
    }
```

Help me please .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a locale issue. I believe you are using Turkish locale in your app. And that causes issues with `strtoupper` function.

There is a similar issue you can take a look here: https://github.com/nrk/predis/issues/372

As a solution, if it's acceptable in your case you can try to change the local. Or as suggested in the issue, you can use the Redis facade Laravel provides. `Redis::EXISTS` like so.